# Проверка на число

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня вот такая проверка есть:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] != "http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27") {
echo "текст"; }
```

Как сделать такую проверку, только заместо цифры 27, поставить какой-нибудь шаблон, который проверяет, если цифра то `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
<?
  //$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
  $ref = "http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27";
  if( preg_match("/(?:\?|&)id=(\d+)(?:$|&)/", $ref) ){
    echo "OK";
  }
?>
```

Для использования убрать `//` со 2 строки и удалить 3 строку

UPD: возможно нужно такое Re:

```
if ( preg_match("/^http\:\/\/site\.loc\/catalog\.php\?id=(\d+)(?:$|&)/", $ref) ){
```

Comment: Вот это правильный ответ : )  
Упс... текст OK не выводица((

Comment: поясните что именно вам надо?<br>
`$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`  - это откуда пришел человек ( практически тоже самое что и предыдущая страница )<br>
Возможно вам надо использовать `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` - это текущие данные адресной строки<br>

Comment: Вобщем так, есть каталоги с такими ссылками  
http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27 Только ID везде разный  
и в каждой этой странице есть кнопка которая переходит на другую страницу,и в этой странице я делаю правило, если человек пришел с каталогов то выводится нужный текст и вот я в начале писал код в впоросе, он работает только на страницу где ID 27

Comment: Со странице http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27 я перехожу на ту страницу где прописал  $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];  
и Выводится http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27

Comment: у вас такой код?

    $ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    if( preg_match("/(?:\?|&)id=(\d+)(?:$|&)/", $ref) ){
      echo "OK";
    }

Comment: Спасибо все работает с вашей помощи) я просто немного ввел вас в заблуждение : )

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27";
if(preg_match("#id=(\d)#ui", $url) && $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] != $url)
{
    echo "текст";
}
```

Как-то так.

Comment: вы не так поняли, у меня просто много страниц таких :  
http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27  
ID можно быть разный, а сейчас надпись "Текст" вышла только на странице где id равен 27

Comment: `(\d)` замените на 27. Или почитайте про strpos.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_GET)) {
        echo 'Empty GET';
}
else
{
    if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
        echo $_GET['id'];
        // Good is true
        // Put a template
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Numeric is empty';
    }
}
```

http://site.loc/catalog.php -> result **Empty GET**

http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=27 -> result **Good is true**

http://site.loc/catalog.php?id=bb -> result **Numeric is empty**

Comment: на ту страничку Гет не передается))

Comment: либо 
    if(intval($_GET['id'])) ...
Если это то, что имеет в виду автор!

Comment: Ну собственно если это то что автор имеет виду)

Comment: там проверка через HTTP_REFERER а не через $_GET['id'] =)

Comment: а в примере тяжело поменять $_GET['id'] на $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]?

сама суть что is_numeric вычесляет наличие цифр!

Comment: все верно, но это не то что нужно было мне : ) и я так же написал, что ввел немного в заблуждение тех кто хотел мне помочь : )